# Why is a default user/password being generated for an Oauth login Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring is generating a default user/password when starting up despite me having configured the application to use Oauth login.
Can anyone see how I have misconfigured the application?
Note the application is reactive using Spring Boot 3.0.6

Thanks for reviewing!

console log

```
2023-05-08T08:32:25.413-04:00  INFO 16296 --- [  restartedMain] ctiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: 5c98715f-86eb-453b-b0ae-b0794350a048

2023-05-08T08:32:25.805-04:00  INFO 16296 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-oauth:
            client-name: my-oauth
            client-id: ${my-oauth-sso-client}
            client-secret: ${my-oauth-sso-secret}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/my-oauth
        provider:
          my-oauth:
            authorization-uri: https://my-oauth.com/v2/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://my-oauth.com/v2/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: https://my-oauth.com/oauth/verify
            user-name-attribute: UserName
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://my-oauth.com/oauth/jwks
          issuer-uri: https://my-oauth.com
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
        ;

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my-oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>Oauth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-oauth</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: I use them in my API server: `.cors().disable()`, `.logout().disable()`, `.formLogin().disable()`, `csrf().disable()` and `.httpBasic().disable()`

Comment: @Numichi - Thanks for the suggestion but it did not help.

Comment: Deactivate from auto-configuration: `ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration` and/or `UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration`